# How can I create a list view with borders in Android?

Tags: android, listview, multiple-columns

I use a multi-column list-view  to display data as like a grid, but I want a list-view with user-defined columns and rows with borders. Suggestions?

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

**main1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cust"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="customer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/order"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="order" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/freight"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="freight" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/station"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="station" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your ListView Design please

Comment: use table row? use a drawable with "border" and set it as the background

Comment: @KrishnaSuthar please visit my question again,i have edited my question with what you demanded early

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method one :**

1) implement a *custom adapter*

2) in the `getview()` method, set a background (with *border*) to the view before returning it.

**Method two:**

use `ArrayAdapter`

1) make an xml file which cointains a `TextView` with a background(which has a *border*)

2) pass the reference to this xml to the `ArrayAdapter`

Here's [a tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/), in case you don't know what i'm talking about.